# Can the same class library be used by a UWP app and MVC web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uwp

Is there a type of c# class library that can be used/referenced by both a UWP (Universal Windows) app and a ASP.NET MVC web application?

I currently have an MVC web application that references a bog standard class library.

When I try to add a reference to that class library from my **UWP** or **Background Application (IoT)** projects it complains. I'm sure they would rather have references to **Class Library (Universal Windows)** project types.

Ideally i'd like a class library that can be referenced by all these project types. I presume this is not possible yet, but I thought i'd ask the question.

Is it possible? I'd rather avoid code duplication.

Do I need some sort of hacky 'include files from another folder' workaround?

Note: I have no intention of moving the web app to ASP.NET core.

[image: Various class library types]

Comment: Definitely, it is what we should/must write any applications. Back end business logic layer and data access layer should not need to know what UI you are using.

Comment: @Win: I'm not sure that addresses the question. The question is asking for a project template, that produces an assembly that can be used both in a UWA as well as an ASP.NET MVC web application. This is not about the UI; those are fundamentally different **platforms**. And while I don't know the answer, I would assume that you can at least share the code, even if you have to compile it into separate assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a portable class library that targets the .NET Framework and UWP should do the job - as long as you don't want to put anything platform specific in it.

Answer (score 0):

**2017/18/19 UPDATE:**

Creating Portable Class Libraries [is now discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/cross-platform/cross-platform-development-with-the-portable-class-library) by Microsoft.

The current preferred method of sharing code between projects targeting different platforms is [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Take a look at the *implementation support* table shown on the page above. If for example your ASP.NET project is on *.NET Framework 4.6.1* or above (preferably on 4.7.1-2), and you are targeting *Windows 10.0.16299* with your UWP app, **you can make your DLL target .NET Standard 2.0**. You can simply reference that class library in both of your projects, just like you'd reference any other library.